# Converting jalali dates to gregorian dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to convert a date in jalali format `۱۱ فروردین ۱۴۰۰` to gregorian format

I tried to use pd.to_datetime but it returned unknown date format

Answer (score 0):

Visit this site https://ghodsizadeh.github.io/jalali-pandas.
and you can visit its git hub too https://github.com/ghodsizadeh/jalali-pandas.
I hope it was helpful.